# Migrating DeleteByQueryPlugin for Elasticsearch from 2.4 to 5.2.2

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-5

In Elasticsearch version 5.x the DeleteByQueryPlugin is removed in favor of Delete By Query API.
To migrate to the new API, i have to replace the 2.3 code:

```
DeleteByQueryResponse response = new     DeleteByQueryRequestBuilder(client(), DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE)
                .setIndices(INDEX_LOCKS)
                .setQuery(rangeQuery(EXPIRES_AT).lte(expiresAt))
                .execute()
                .actionGet();
```

with the new 5.x DeleteByQueryAction code:

```
BulkIndexByScrollResponse response = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client())
                .filter(rangeQuery(EXPIRES_AT).lte(expiresAt))
                .source(INDEX_LOCKS)
                .get();
```

This is working fine if i start the server and testing the code. But it is not working for my integration tests. The following test code throws an exception:

Testcode:

```
public class DeleteByQueryTest extends ESIntegTestCase {

    private static final String INDEX_LOCKS = "locks";
    private static final String INDEX_ARTICLES = "articles";
    private static final String LOCK_TYPE = "lock";
    private static final String LOCK_ID = "something";

    @Before
    public void waitForIndex() {
        createIndex(INDEX_LOCKS, INDEX_ARTICLES);
        ensureGreen(INDEX_LOCKS, INDEX_ARTICLES);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDeleteByQuery() {
        IndexResponse indexResponse = client().prepareIndex(INDEX_LOCKS, LOCK_TYPE, LOCK_ID).setSource("{}").setCreate(true).get();
        assertThat(indexResponse.getId(), is(LOCK_ID));
        refresh();

        BulkIndexByScrollResponse response = DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client())
            .filter(idsQuery(LOCK_TYPE).addIds(LOCK_ID))
            .source(INDEX_LOCKS)
            .get();

        assertThat(response.getDeleted(), is(1L));
    }
}
```

The exception which occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find action [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.DeleteByQueryAction@5794e1cf] to execute

    at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([F8694D27C3481CF8:12F0CCE2BD73E437]:0)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.transportAction(NodeClient.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.FilterClient.doExecute(FilterClient.java:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.get(ActionRequestBuilder.java:62)
    at de.sabio.search.indexer.lock.DeleteByQueryTest.shouldDeleteByQuery(DeleteByQueryTest.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.invoke(RandomizedRunner.java:1713)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$8.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:907)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$9.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:943)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$10.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:957)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleSetupTeardownChained$1.evaluate(TestRuleSetupTeardownChained.java:49)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.AbstractBeforeAfterRule$1.evaluate(AbstractBeforeAfterRule.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleThreadAndTestName$1.evaluate(TestRuleThreadAndTestName.java:48)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleMarkFailure$1.evaluate(TestRuleMarkFailure.java:47)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:367)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl.forkTimeoutingTask(ThreadLeakControl.java:811)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$3.evaluate(ThreadLeakControl.java:462)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner.runSingleTest(RandomizedRunner.java:916)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$5.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:802)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$6.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:852)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.RandomizedRunner$7.evaluate(RandomizedRunner.java:863)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.AbstractBeforeAfterRule$1.evaluate(AbstractBeforeAfterRule.java:45)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleStoreClassName$1.evaluate(TestRuleStoreClassName.java:41)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:40)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule$1.evaluate(NoShadowingOrOverridesOnMethodsRule.java:40)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleAssertionsRequired$1.evaluate(TestRuleAssertionsRequired.java:53)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleMarkFailure$1.evaluate(TestRuleMarkFailure.java:47)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreAfterMaxFailures.java:64)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites$1.evaluate(TestRuleIgnoreTestSuites.java:54)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.rules.StatementAdapter.evaluate(StatementAdapter.java:36)
    at com.carrotsearch.randomizedtesting.ThreadLeakControl$StatementRunner.run(ThreadLeakControl.java:367)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anyone have the same problem and knows what to do?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add the reindex plugin in test code:

```
@Override
protected Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> nodePlugins() {
    return Collections.singleton(ReindexPlugin.class);
}

@Override
protected Collection<Class<? extends Plugin>> transportClientPlugins() {
    return Collections.singleton(ReindexPlugin.class);
}
```